# Android gallery not updated after ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Tags: java, android, android-intent, photo, mediastore

I'm using `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` to take a picture with `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` to point to the `Uri` for the DCIM/Camera directory where all the other photo/video files are stored.

The photo file is successfully taken and I can see it using ES File Explorer and can view it inside my app. However it is not shown in the gallery when I use `Intent.ACTION_PICK`

```
Intent selectPictureIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        selectPictureIntent.setType("image/*");
```

I've read the other topics on updating the Gallery after the picture comes back using

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, 
                 Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

and also

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, _outputMediaUri);     
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

What's going on here :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

why did you use LocalBroadcastManager? LocalBroadcastManager can only send broadcast data inside of your app. Try to use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, _outputMediaUri);     
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Gallery always listens to URI change. After file event broadcast to Gallery, the data stored in Gallery will be updated.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem. This code was in a fragment so it ended up as `getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent)`. Thanks.

Comment: please take a look at this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096845/android-how-to-add-recorded-video-in-gallery-and-create-thumbnail-for-it

Answer (score 0):

it also can problem with KITKAT build version.. for sure you can use this code:

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(out); \\out is your output file
                    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
                    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
                } else {
                    sendBroadcast(new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                            Uri.parse("file://"
                                    + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
                }
```